# Minimax not running optimally

Tags: python-3.x, minimax

I have written a minimax algorithm for tic tac toe with alpha-beta pruning (might be the problem, was working fine before), but it is not always choosing the optimal move (ex. not taking an instant win).
However, it will still block any ways you can win.

Example:

```
Do you want to go first (y/n)? n
Going in: 2,2
...
.X.
...
Where do you want to go (row,col)? 1,2
.O.
.X.
...
Going in: 1,1
XO.
.X.
...
Where do you want to go (row,col)? 1,3
XOO
.X.
...
Going in: 2,3 (?)
XOO
.XX
...
Where do you want to go (row,col)?
```

Code (for full see [here](https://repl.it/Gesg/latest)):

```
def miniMaxScore(self,isComp,alpha=None,beta=None):
    """Get score of current game"""
    if self.isFinished(): #if game is complete, score it and return
      return self.score()
    if alpha==None:
      alpha=float('-inf')
    if beta==None:
      beta=float('+inf')
    if isComp:
      bestValue=float('-inf')
      for move in self.empty():
        new=self.fillIn(*move,2)
        currValue=new.miniMaxScore(False,alpha,beta)
        alpha=max(alpha,currValue)
        bestValue=max(currValue,bestValue)
#        if beta<=alpha:
#          break
      return bestValue
    else:
      bestValue=float('+inf')
      for move in self.empty():
        new=self.fillIn(*move,2)
        currValue=new.miniMaxScore(True,alpha,beta)
        beta=min(currValue,beta)
        bestValue=min(currValue,bestValue)
#        if beta<=alpha:
#          break
      return bestValue
def getAIMove(self):
  """Return the x and y positions of the optimal AI move"""
  scores=[]
  for possibleMove in self.empty():
    possibleNext=self.fillIn(*possibleMove,2)
    scores.append((possibleMove,possibleNext.miniMaxScore(False)))
  return max(scores,key=lambda x:x[1])[0] #best move
```

EDIT: removed pruning, but still broken

Answer (score 0):

In the one-but-last line you need to pass `False` instead of `True` to `miniMaxScore()`, since you just (temporarily) played a "computer" move already, i.e. `possibleMove`. `possibleNext` is a game state where the human opponent must play.

Comment: EDIT: I have tried that, but it still performs suboptimally (question edited)

Comment: That is what I mean: it is the AI move in memory producing `possibleNext`. And it is potentially a move that will be returned by the function. I add the word "temporarily" in the text now to avoid confusion. The code is *trying* moves, to see which of those is the best move for the AI side. So they are AI-sided moves.